# ASP.NET MVC Code Model Binding Failure with Json Body

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to get a JQuery .ajax post of a Json array to bind up with an ASP.NET Core MVC Controller Action and can't get the model binding to work.

The problem is downstream of this but I include it for completeness.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Campaign/RosterMaintenanceAttribute",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(attributeData),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (request) {
        alert(request);
    }
});
```

Here is what the outgoing Request looks like in the browser:

[image]

Here is what the Payload looks like (I've expanded one of the array items for clarity):

[image]

Here is what the controller action signature looks like:

```
public IActionResult RosterMaintenanceAttribute([FromBody] IEnumerable<AttributeModel> attributes)
```

I've tried having the parameter as a string but no matter what data type I use, the parameter resolves to null.  To be cclear, this is an MVC Controller, not an Api Controller and I'm not sure if the [FromBody] works in MVC Controllers.

The AttributeModel class looks like this:

```
public class AttributeModel
{
    public Guid CharacterAttributeId { get; set; }
    public Guid CharacterId { get; set; }

    public Guid AttributeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }
    public int AttributeModifier { get; set; }
    public string AttributeNote { get; set; }
    public int AttributeOrdinal { get; set; }
    public bool Proficient { get; set; }
}
```

This is what the payload looks like with the .attributes syntax
[image]

This is what the Request looks like just inside the Controller
[image]

Comment: Include the Controller definition along with the action signature already shown as well as all used attributes.

Comment: The Controller literally does nothing more than return and I've got a break point sitting there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the data types of the fields.  It seems the model binder doesn't like mapping into ints and bools - Guids are okay though (those are the 3 that I have to deal with, not sure about others).  I've verified that trying to map to an int **or** a bool cause the binding failure.

I've decided to send the array without the root element

```
data: JSON.stringify(attributeData.attributes)
```

I used a great tool (shout out to http://json2csharp.com/) and simply pasted in the body that I have in the browser request, generating this:

```
public class httpAttributeModel
{
    public string CharacterAttributeId { get; set; }
    public string CharacterId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeOrdinal { get; set; }
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }
    public string AttributeModifier { get; set; }
    public string Proficient { get; set; }
    public string AttributeNote { get; set; }
}
```

With this Controller signature:

```
public IActionResult RosterMaintenanceAttribute([FromBody] List<httpAttributeModel> attributes)
```

This works.So I started tweaking data types to try and match the original model I was using to receive the payload, seeing where it failed.  The actual values for both the int and bool are valid for the type (except the quotes around them from the stringify) but that is where things stop working.  I don't know if there is anything to do on the client side to denote data type or more likely, something on the server side that helps the model binder?  For this issue, this is good enough, I can convert the int and bool values once I'm in the Controller.

In my final solution, in the model above I have the first three fields set as Guids and the rest as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType: "json"

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Campaign/RosterMaintenanceAttribute",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(attributeData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (request) {
        alert(request);
    }
});
```